# Wordpress wp_remote_post not working

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get response from the URL `https://businessenergy.energyhelpline.com/interface/list.php` 
by using  `wp_remote_post` but that is giving me error with message

> Something went wrong: SSL: certificate subject name '*.pure360.com'
>   does not match target host name 'businessenergy.energyhelpline.com'

can someone please help me? My code is given below.

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://businessenergy.energyhelpline.com/interface/list.php', array(
                                                'method' => 'POST',
                                                'timeout' => 45,
                                                'redirection' => 5,
                                                'httpversion' => '1.0',
                                                'blocking' => true,
                                                'headers' => array(),
                                                'body' => array( 'email' => 'abc@abc.com', 'mobile' => '9556638896', 'Business' => 'Business', 'FirstName'=>'abc','LastName'=>'abc', 'listName'=> 'SMS MIC & Ener Bus Combined 190912','accName'=>'businessenergy', 'fullEmailValidationInd'=>'Y', 'successUrl'=>'NO-REDIRECT', 'errorUrl'=>'' ),
                                                'cookies' => array()
                                            )
                                        );

                                        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
                                           $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
                                           echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
                                        } else {
                                           echo 'Response:<pre>';
                                           print_r( $response );
                                           echo '</pre>';
                                        }
```

Comment: The error message is clear, isn't it? You try to connect to `https` with bad certificate.

Comment: That is correct your certificate is invalid! Try connecting without using HTTPS or install a valid certificate!

Comment: Thank you Panther and Sumit  for help, it's done by using HTTP.